# $this-> form-> input cakephp stripslash

Tags: php, cakephp

I am new in `cakephp` and want to use `stripslash`.

below is the code is used for display the value in edit mode which is already in `DB`. and I am using `addslashes` when saving the value.

```
 <?php echo $this->Form->input('text', array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => "Description", 'label' => 'Description', 'data-fv-notempty-message' => __('notEmpty'), 'required' => 'required')); ?>
```

Comment: You dont need to do that unless you are using CakePHP ORM's  find() and save() methods. CakePHP takes care of it.

Comment: It is still wrong. Do not mess with slashes at all. Absolutely 0 need to do that.